# c# console stdin input stream reading

Tags: c#, stream, inputstream, stdin

I have this thread that runs code of the following form where strm1 in the case i am testing is the console stdin.

```
while (true) { strm1.Read(buffer, 0, 1); dosomething1(buffer); }
```

If enter is pressed, `dosomething1()` calls `dosomething2()`. However, even when i press enter, i still have to press some other key for `dosomething2()` to run. How can i fix this? thankyou.

Comment: How and where is dosomething2() called

Comment: We need to see the "dosomething1()" method code.

Comment: in dosomething1(), when dosomething1() detects that buffer is \n. why is this donwvoted!???

Comment: Try to use Environment.NewLine instead of '\n'. You were downvoted due to lack of information.

Comment: Depends - whats in "Dosomething1"?

Comment: gilad 1: why do you need it? anyway it is of the form 'sb.append(encoding.utf8.getstring(buffer)); if (buffer[0] == 10) dosomething2(buffer)' where sb is a stringbuilder. gilad 2: what lack? i see no lack.

Comment: btw when i say the buffer is \n, since as evident from the read call, only one byte is written to the buffer, so only a char will be produced. aka when i say \n, i mean (char)10. so environment.newline should not help. see my comment for the answer below for more explanation.

Comment: bugfinder: see my second comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved the problem: by replacing the `Stream`s to `StreamReader`s! Probably a Microsoft implementation problem, but at least it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what checks your code performs, but remember that in Windows, Environment.NewLine is two chars: CR (\r), LF (\n).

Comment: yes, i know this. this shouldnt affect it, since if when an enter is pressed, because the read is in a while loop, itll still read the \n.